# Openlayers, when panning (holding click), features don't render

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

If you pan in this example away from the features, then you pan back but you don't release the click, you hold it, the feature isn't visible unless you release the click.

Why does that happens and how to fix that?

Comment: You would need to set `updateWhileInteracting: true,` in the layer options https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

layer options - updateWhileInteracting: true